# Creating an GetAttributeRequest in Java

Tags: c#, java, amazon-sqs

I have been attempting to implement a GetAttributeRequest in Java that has similar functionality to the following C# code.

```
try
{
  long epochWindowTime = ToEpochTimeInMilliseconds(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(this.SQSWindow));
  int numberOfMessages = 0;

   // 1st query to determine the # of Messages available in the queue
   using (AmazonSQSClient client = new AmazonSQSClient(
           this.AWSAccessKey, this.AWSSecretAccessKey,
           ew AmazonSQSConfig() { ServiceURL = this.AWSSQSServiceUrl }))
  {
  // get the NumberOfMessages to optimize how to Receive all of the messages from the queue
     GetQueueAttributesRequest attributesRequest = new GetQueueAttributesRequest();
     attributesRequest.QueueUrl = this.QueueUrl;
     attributesRequest.AttributeName.Add("ApproximateNumberOfMessages");
     numberOfMessages = client.GetQueueAttributes(attributesRequest).GetQueueAttributesResult.ApproximateNumberOfMessages;
  }
```

My attempt at a Java implementation looks as follows,

```
try
{
    long epochWindowTime;
    int numberOfMessages = 0;
    Map<String, String> attributes;

    // Setup the SQS client
    AmazonSQS client = new AmazonSQSClient(new 
            ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider());

    client.setEndpoint(this.AWSSQSServiceUrl);

    // get the NumberOfMessages to optimize how to 
    // Receive all of the messages from the queue

    GetQueueAttributesRequest attributesRequest = 
            new GetQueueAttributesRequest();
    attributesRequest.setQueueUrl(this.QueueUrl);
    //attributesRequest.setAttributeNames();
    attributes = client.getQueueAttributes(attributesRequest).
            getAttributes();

    numberOfMessages = Integer.valueOf(attributes.get(
            "ApproximateNumberOfMessages")).intValue();

}catch (AmazonServiceException ase){
    ase.printStackTrace();
}catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
    ace.printStackTrace();

}
```

Because the Java AmazonSQS implementation of adding attribute names requires as Collection I do not understand how I would add the "ApproximateNumberOfMessages" properly.

I am also curious if there is a better alternative to the

```
new AmazonSQSClient(new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider());
```

that is closer to the C# implementation? The reason for this is that this method is intended to be used as part of an SDK, and the  AWSAccessKey, and AWSSecretAccessKey will be part of a separate configuration file. Is my only option to create my own AWSCredentialsProvider?

Comment: Is GetQueueAttributesRequest.withAttributeNames(...) the correct alternative to attributesRequest.AttributeName.Add("ApproximateNumberOfMessages");?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`withAttributeNames` accepts a vararg list of attributes.

```
String attr = "ApproximateNumberOfMessages";
Map<String, String> attributes = client.getQueueAttributes(new GetQueueAttributesRequest(this.QueueUrl).withAttributeNames(attr)).getAttributes();
int count = Integer.parseInt(attributes.get(attr));
```

The Java SDK has multiple methods of constructing credentials. Using `BasicAWSCredentials` is the quickest if the keys are readily available to you.

```
AmazonSQS client = new AmazonSQSClient(new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretKey"));
```